# How to hide System.Object members in Intellisense when importing a C# dll into Python

Tags: c#, python, dll, intellisense

I want to hide the System.Object methods [Equals(), GetType(), ToString(), GetHashCode()] from showing in Intellisense in a python application when I import a C# dll. I've tried the IFluentInterface solution. I am inheriting the interface into my parent class which is getting instantiated in python.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public interface IFluentInterface
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    Type GetType();

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    int GetHashCode();

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    string ToString();

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    bool Equals(object obj);
}
```